# Schematic library generated content provider can't be named in manifest

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm using the Schematic library by SimonVT. The manifest throws an error no matter what I put in the "android:name" section. When I use the names .data.generated.ActivityProvider, data.provider.ActivityProvider, and any variation of the two I see a ClassNotFound Error. When I go to ActivityProvider.java and provide the name in the annotation, I received a NullPointerException.

Recap

```
<provider
            android:authorities="com.philliphsu.clock2.data.ActivityProvider"
            android:name="com.philliphsu.clock2.data.provider.ActivityProvider"
            android:exported="false">
```

and

```
<provider
            android:authorities="com.philliphsu.clock2.data.ActivityProvider"
            android:name="com.philliphsu.clock2.data.generated.ActivityProvider"
            android:exported="false">
```

return a ClassNotFoundException

```
@ContentProvider(authority = ActivityProvider.AUTHORITY, database = ActivityDatabase.class,
name = "com.philliphsu.clock2.data.provider.ActivityProvider", packageName = "com.philliphsu.clock2.debug")
public class ActivityProvider {
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.philliphsu.clock2.data.ActivityProvider";
```

led to the gradle task app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac failing because of a NullPointerException. Any tips that would enable me to successfully name the content provider in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

It is already answered. [Please check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30499914/6227977).

[image: Answer of this question]